# Ошибка startForeground в Android 8.1

Tags: java, android

Вот такая проблема: показывается список песен - нажимаю на на любую, для воспроизведения, показывает ошибку `android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=My channel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)`
Как я понял проблема тут:

```java
 @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);


            builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                    .setTicker(songTitle)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Playing")
                    .setContentText(songTitle);
            Notification not = builder.build();
            startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
}
```

С языком Java знаком недавно

Comment: Разрешение <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> добавили в манифесте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с Android Oreo при создании notification нужно указать chanelId в билдере:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(textTitle)
        .setContentText(textContent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

Из документации:

> Notice that the **NotificationCompat.Builder** constructor requires that you provide a channel ID. This is required for compatibility with Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, but is ignored by older versions.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#SimpleNotification